# Return magic value, throw exception or return false on failure?

Tags: c#, .net, exceptions, error-handling

I sometimes end up having to write a method or property *for a class library* for which it is not exceptional to have no real answer, but a failure. Something cannot be determined, is not available, not found, not currently possible or there is no more data available.

I think there are three possible solutions for such a relatively *non-exceptional* situation to indicate failure in C# 4:

- return a magic value that has no meaning otherwise (such as `null` and `-1`);
- throw an exception (e.g. `KeyNotFoundException`);
- return `false` and provide the actual return value in an `out` parameter, (such as [`Dictionary<,>.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx)).

So the questions are: *in which non-exceptional situation should I throw an exception?* And if I should not throw: *when is returning a magic value perferred above implementing a `Try*` method with an `out` parameter*? (To me the `out` parameter seems dirty, and it is more work to use it properly.)

I'm looking for factual answers, such as answers involving design guidelines (I don't know any about `Try*` methods), usability (as I ask this for a class library), consistency with the BCL, and readability.

---

In the .NET Framework Base Class Library, all three methods are used:

- return a magic value that has no meaning otherwise:

  - [`Collection<T>.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132410.aspx) returns -1,
  - [`StreamReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8.aspx) returns -1,
  - [`Math.Sqrt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt.aspx) returns NaN,
  - [`Hashtable.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item.aspx) returns null;
- throw an exception:

  - [`Dictionary<,>.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) throws KeyNotFoundException,
  - [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx) throws FormatException; or
- return `false` and provide the actual return value in an `out` parameter:

  - [`Dictionary<,>.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx),
  - [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx).

Note that as `Hashtable` was created in the time when there were no generics in C#, it uses `object` and can therefore return `null` as a magic value. But with generics, exceptions are used in `Dictionary<,>`, and initially it didn't have `TryGetValue`. Apparently insights change.

Obviously, the `Item`-`TryGetValue` and `Parse`-`TryParse` duality is there for a reason, so I assume that throwing exceptions for non-exceptional failures is in C# 4 *not done*. However, the `Try*` methods didn't always exist, even when `Dictionary<,>.Item` existed.

Comment: I would use exceptions in the non-recoverable situations. E.g. accessing an array out of range, or parsing an word as a number.

In situations where you may expect problems, you can provide Try* methods such as "TryParse" or "TryGetValue", where you return false in case of problems (almost anticipated), and fetch the value in some out parameter.

The first examples using the -1 value, I think is remniscent of the C days.

Comment: "exceptions mean bugs". asking a dictionary for a non-existant item is a bug; asking a stream to read data when it's an EOF happens every time you use a stream. (this summarizes the long a beautifully formatted answer I didn't get a chance to submit :) )

Comment: @EricJ. Could you explain that? I modified the question and think it asks for facts. There must be a solution that is not subjective but something that I can use in specific situations. I propose only three options, so I just expect some arguments as to which one is best in a particular situation.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I hope you still have it somewhere: you may resubmit your answer. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @CarloV.Dango Your perspective is not in any of the current answers, so if you wish, you may add it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: It's not that I think your question is too broad, it's that it's not a constructive question. There's no canonical answer as the answers are already showing.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If the answer was straight-forward and obvious then I wouldn't have asked the question. The fact that people can argue why a given choice is preferable from any standpoint (such as performance, readability, usability, maintainability, design guidelines or consistency) makes it inherently non-canonical yet answerable to my satisfaction. All questions can be answered somewhat subjective. Apparently you expect a question to have mostly similar answers for it to be a good question.

Comment: @Virtlink: George is a community-elected moderator who volunteers a great deal of his time to help maintain Stack Overflow.  He stated why he closed the question, and the FAQ backs him up.

Comment: The question belongs here, not because it is subjective, but because it is *conceptual.*  Rule of thumb: if you're sitting in front of your IDE coding, ask it on Stack Overflow.  If you're standing in front of a whiteboard brainstorming, ask it here on Programmers.

Comment: There is another option (mentioned in some answers), close to 3rd one. Return value by modifiing some parameter. It is side effect, but if you want to eg. return some 3d point and it will be used in tight loop, allowing to save object creation can be important.

Comment: related: [Exceptions: Why throw early? Why catch late?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/231057/exceptions-why-throw-early-why-catch-late)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't think that your examples are really equivalent. There are three distinct groups, each with it's own rationale for its behaviour.

1. Magic value is a good option when there is an "until" condition such as `StreamReader.Read` or when there is a simple to use value that will never be a valid answer (-1 for `IndexOf`).
2. Throw exception when the semantics of the function is that the caller is sure that it will work. In this case a non-existing key or a bad double format is truly exceptional.
3. Use an out parameter and return a bool if the semantics is to probe if the operation is possible or not.

The examples you provide are perfectly clear for cases 2 and 3. For the magic values, it can be argued if this is a good design decision or not in all cases.

The `NaN` returned by `Math.Sqrt` is a special case - it follows the floating point standard.

Comment: Disagree with number 1. Magic values are never a good option as they require the next coder to know the significance of the magic value. They also hurt readability. I can think of no instance in which the use of a magic value is better than the Try pattern.

Comment: But what about the `Either<TLeft, TRight>` monad?

Comment: @0b101010: just spent some time looking up how streamreader.read can safely return -1...

Answer (score 36):

You're trying to communicate to the user of the API what they have to do.  If you throw an exception, there's nothing forcing them to catch it, and only reading the documentation is going to let them know what all the possibilities are.  Personally I find it slow and tedious to dig into the documentation to find all the exceptions that a certain method might throw (even if it's in intellisense, I still have to copy them out manually).

A magic value still requires you to read the documentation, and possibly reference some `const` table to decode the value.  At least it doesn't have the overhead of an exception for what you call a non-exceptional occurrence.

That is why even though `out` parameters are sometimes frowned upon, I prefer that method, with the `Try...` syntax.  It's canonical .NET and C# syntax.  You're communicating to the user of the API that they have to check the return value before using the result.  You can also include a second `out` parameter with a helpful error message, which again helps with debugging.  That's why I vote for the `Try...` with `out` parameter solution.

Another option is to return a special "result" object, though I find this a lot more tedious:

```
interface IMyResult
{
    bool Success { get; }
    // Only access this if Success is true
    MyOtherClass Result { get; }
    // Only access this if Success is false
    string ErrorMessage { get; }
}
```

Then your function *looks* right because it only has input parameters and it only returns one thing.  It's just that the one thing it returns is kind of a tuple.

In fact, if you're into that kind of thing, you can use the new `Tuple<>` classes that were introduced in .NET 4.  Personally I don't like the fact that the meaning of each field is less explicit because I can't give `Item1` and `Item2` useful names.

Comment: Personally, I often use a result container like your `IMyResult` cause it is possible to communicate a more complex result than just `true` or `false` or the result value. `Try*()` is only useful for simple stuff like string to int conversion.

Comment: Good post. For me, I prefer the Result structure idiom that you outlined above as opposed to splitting between "return" values and "out" parameters. Keeps it neat and tidy.

Comment: The problem with the second out parameter is when you are 50 functions deep in a complex program, how do you then communicate that error message back to the user? Throwing an exception is much simpler than have layers of checking errors. When you get one just throw it and it doesn't matter how deep you are.

Comment: @rolls - When we use output objects we suppose that the immediate caller will do whatever he wants with the output: treat it locally, ignore it, or bubble up by throwing that wrapped into an exception. It's the best of both words - the caller can clearly see all possible outputs (with enums, etc), can decide what do to with the error, and don't need to try-catch on each call. If you're mostly expecting to handle the result immediately or ignore it, return objects are easier. If you want to throw all errors to upper layers, exceptions are easier.

Comment: Except you can forget to check the error message. Or you can check it and it is not obvious whether the result is safe to use. Exception is very explicit, things are broken and you absolutely cannot use the result.

Comment: This is just reinventing checked exceptions in C# in a much more tedious way than checked exceptions in Java.

Answer (score 18):

As your examples already show, each such case must be evaluated separately and there is a considerable spectrum of gray between "exceptional circumstances" and "flow control", especially if your method is intended to be reusable, and might be used in quite different patterns than it was originally designed for.  Do not expect us all here to agree on what "non-exceptional" means, especially if you immediately discuss the possibility of using "exceptions" to implement that.

We might also not agree on what design makes the code easiest to read and maintain, but I will assume that the library designer has a clear personal vision of that and only needs to balance it against the other considerations involved.

**Short answer**

Follow your gut feelings except when you are designing pretty fast methods and expect a possibility of unforeseen reuse.

**Long answer**

Each future caller may freely translate between error codes and exceptions as it wishes in both directions; this makes the two design approaches almost equivalent except for performance, debugger-friendliness and some restricted interoperability contexts.  This usually boils down to performance, so let's focus on that.

- As a rule of thumb, expect that throwing an exception is 200x slower than a regular return (in reality, there is a significant variance in that).
- As another rule of thumb, throwing an exception may often allow much cleaner code compared with the crudest of magic values, because you are not relying on the programmer translating the error code into another error code, as it travels through multiple layers of client code towards a point where there is enough context for handling it in a consistent and adequate way.  (Special case: `null` tends to fare better here than other magic values because of its tendency to automatically translating itself to a `NullReferenceException` in case of some, but not all types of defects; usually, but not always, quite close to the source of the defect.)

So what's the lesson?

For a function that's called just a few times during the lifetime of an application (like the app initialization), use anything that gives you cleaner, easier to understand code.  Performance cannot be a concern.

For a throw-away function, use anything that gives you cleaner code.  Then do some profiling (if needed at all) and change exceptions to return codes if they are among the suspected top bottlenecks based on measurements or overall program structure.

For an expensive reusable function, use anything that gives you cleaner code.  If you basically always have to undergo a network roundtrip or parse an on-disk XML file, the overhead of throwing an exception is probably negligible.  It is more important to not lose  details of any failure, not even accidentally, than to return from a "non-exceptional failure" extra fast.

A lean reusable function requires more thought.  By employing exceptions, you are *forcing* something like a 100 times slow down on callers who will see the exception on half of their (many) calls, if the body of the function executes very fast.  Exceptions are still a design option, but you will have to provide a low overhead alternative for callers who can not afford this.  Let's look at an example.

You list a great example of `Dictionary<,>.Item`, which, loosely speaking, changed from returning `null` values to throwing `KeyNotFoundException` between .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0 (only if you are willing to consider `Hashtable.Item` to be its practical non-generic forerunner).  The reason of this "change" is not without interest here.  Performance optimization of value types (no more boxing) made the original magic value (`null`) a non-option; `out` parameters would just bring a small part of the performance cost back.  This latter performance consideration is completely *negligible* in comparison with the overhead of throwing a `KeyNotFoundException`, but the exception design is still superior here.  Why?

- ref/out parameters incur their costs every time, not just in the "failure" case
- Anyone who cares can call `Contains` before any call to the indexer, and this pattern reads completely naturally.  If a developer wants to but forgets to call `Contains`, no performance issues can creep in; `KeyNotFoundException` is loud enough to be noticed and fixed.

Comment: I think 200x is being optimistic about the perf of exceptions... see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/10/01/51524.aspx "Performance and Trends" section just before the comments.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - Well, maybe.  That article uses a 1% failure rate to discuss the topic which isn't an entirely different ballpark.  My own thoughts and vaguely remembered measurements would be from the context of table-implemented C++ (see Section 5.4.1.2 of [this report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf), where one problem is that the first exception of its kind is likely to start with a page fault (drastic and variable but amortized one time overhead).  But I'll do and post an experiment with .NET 4 and possibly tweak this ballpark value.  I already stress the variance.

Comment: Is the cost for ref/out parameters _that high_ then? How so? And calling `Contains` before a call to an indexer might cause a race condition that does not have to be present with `TryGetValue`.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - Experimented finished.  I was lazy and used mono on Linux. [Exceptions](http://ideone.com/Z3AO2) gave me ~563000 throws in 3 seconds.  [Returns](http://ideone.com/3x9OA) gave me ~10900000  returns in 3 seconds.  That's 1:20, not even 1:200.  I still recommend thinking 1:100+ for any more realistic code.  (out param variant, as I had predicted, had negligible costs - I actually suspect that the jitter probably had optimized the call away completely in my minimalistic example if there was no exception thrown, regardless of the signature.)

Comment: @Virtlink - Agreed on thread safety in general, but given that you referred to .NET 4 in particular, use `ConcurrentDictionary` for multi-threaded access and `Dictionary` for single threaded access for optimal performance.  That is, not using ``Contains` does NOT make the code thread safe with this particular `Dictionary` class.

Comment: @JirkaHanika I agree on using `ConcurrentDictionary`. But if you were to write a thread-safe try-and-get method for your own (concurrent) class, which approach would you choose?

Comment: @Virtlink - As per my answer.   If the method body is just a few cycles, I'd probably choose TryXxx if I could not return a null or a natural magic value.  If it's heavy-weight, I am using exceptions all the time, and I LOVE the unhandled stacktraces that I occasionally see in defect reports compared to corrupt heap or swallowed negative numbers in some other code.  Mind you, this is just one team's preference.  Find yours.

Answer (score 10):

> What is the best thing to do in such a relatively non-exceptional situation to indicate failure, and why?

You should not allow failure.

I know, it's hand-wavey and idealistic, but hear me out. When doing design, there are a number of cases where you have the opportunity to favor a version that has no failure modes. Instead of having a 'FindAll' that fails, LINQ uses a where clause that simply returns an empty enumerable. Instead of having an object that needs to be initialized before used, let the constructor initialize the object (or initialize when the not-initialized is detected). The key is removing the failure branch in consumer code. This is the problem, so focus on it.

Another strategy for this is the `KeyNotFound` sscenario. In almost every codebase I've worked on since 3.0, something like this extension method exists:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions {
    public static V GetValue<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> arg, K key, Func<K,V> ifNotFound) {
        if (!arg.ContainsKey(key)) {
            return ifNotFound(key);
        }

        return arg[key];
    }
}
```

There is no real failure mode for this. `ConcurrentDictionary` has a similar `GetOrAdd` built in.

All that said, there will always be times where it's simply unavoidable. All three have their place, but I would favor the first option. Despite all that is made of null's danger, it's well known and fits into a lot of the 'item not found' or 'result is not applicable' scenarios that make up the "not exceptional failure" set. Especially when you're making nullable value types, the significance of the 'this might fail' is very explicit in code and hard to forget/screw up.

The second option is good enough when your user does something dumb. Gives you a string with the wrong format, tries to set the date to December 42nd... something that you want things to blow up quickly and spectacularly during testing so that bad code is identified and fixed.

The last option is one I increasingly dislike. Out parameters are awkward, and tend to violate some of the best practices when making methods, like focusing on one thing and not having side effects. Plus, the out param is usually only meaningful during success. That said, they are essential for certain operations that are usually constrained by concurrency concerns, or performance considerations (where you don't want to make a second trip to the DB for example).

If the return value and out param are non-trivial, then Scott Whitlock's suggestion about a result object is preferred (like Regex's `Match` class).

Comment: Pet peeve here: `out` parameters are completely orthogonal to the issue of side effects.  Modifying a `ref` parameter is a side effect, and modifying an object's state that you pass in via an input parameter is a side effect, but an `out` parameter is just an awkward way of making a function return more than one value.  *There is no side effect, just multiple return values.*

Comment: I said _tend to_, because of how people use them. Like you say, they're simply multiple return values.

Comment: But if you dislike out parameters and use exceptions to blow things up spectacularly when the format is wrong... how do you then handle the case where your format is user input? Then either a user can blow things up, or one incurs the performance penalty of throwing and then catching an exception. Right?

Comment: @virtlink by having a distinct validation method. You need it _anyways_ to provide proper messages to the UI before they submit it.

Comment: @Telastyn I agree, but how do then validate, for example, a user-entered date without `Parse` (due to the exception penalty) or `TryParse` (due to the out parameter)? Any thoughts?

Comment: @virtlink if you were making your own date class, you would have a validator that returned a set of error conditions to mark the parse failure. It's dicier with something like date that has a lot of formats, but it's good for things like phone numbers or zip codes or ssns

Comment: There is a legitimate pattern for out parameters, and that is a function that has overloads that return different types.  Overload resolution won't work for return types, but it will for out parameters.

Comment: This reminded me of the famous quote: "*Failure is not an option.*" Also: "*The difficult we do right away, the impossible takes a bit longer.*" (As for Exceptions)

Answer (score 3):

Always prefer to throw an exception. It's got a uniform interface amongst all functions that could fail, and it indicates failure as noisily as possible- a very desirable property.

Note that `Parse` and `TryParse` aren't really the same thing apart from failure modes. The fact that `TryParse` can also return the value is somewhat orthogonal, really. Consider the situation where, for example, you're validating some input. You don't actually care what the value is, as long as it's valid. And there's nothing wrong with offering a kind of `IsValidFor(arguments)` function. But it can never be the *primary* mode of operation.

Comment: If you're dealing with a large number of calls to a method, exceptions can have a huge negative effect on performance.  Exceptions should be reserved for exceptional conditions, and would be perfectly acceptable for validating form input, but not for parsing numbers from large files.

Comment: That's a more specialist need, not the general case.

Comment: So you say.  But you did use the word "always." :)

Comment: @DeadMG, agreed with RobertHarvey although I think the answer was overly voted down, if it were modified to reflect "most of the time" and then point out exceptions (no pun intended) to the general case when it comes to frequently used high performance calls to consider other options.

Comment: Exceptions are not expensive.  Catching deeply thrown exceptions can be expensive as the system has to unwind the stack to the nearest critical point.  But that "expensive" is relatively tiny and shouldn't be feared even in tight nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the magic value (including a boolean return value) is not that great a solution, except as an "end-of-range" marker. Reason: The semantics are not explicit, even if you examine the methods of the object. You have to actually read the full documentation for the entire object right down to "oh yeah, if it returns -42 that means bla bla bla".

This solution may be used for historical reasons or for performance reasons, but should otherwise be avoided.

This leaves two general cases: Probing or exceptions.

Here the rule of thumb is that the program should not react to exceptions except as to handle when the program /unintentionally/ violates some condition. Probing should be used to ensure that this doesn't happen. Hence, an exception either means that the relevant probing was not performed in advance, or that something entirely unexpected has happened.

Example:

You want to create a file from a given path.

You should use the File object to evaluate in advance whether this path is legal for file creation or writing.

If your program somehow still ends up trying to write to a path that is illegal or otherwise not writable, you should get an excaption. This could happen due to a race condition (some other user removed the directory, or made it read-only, after you probl)

The task of handling an unexpected fail (signalled by an exception) and checking if the conditions are right for the operation in advance (probing) will usually be structured differently, and should therefore use different mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Try` pattern is the best choice, when code just indicate what happened. I hate out param and like nullable object. I've created following class

```
public sealed class Bag<TValue>
{
    public Bag(TValue value, bool hasValue = true)
    {
        HasValue = hasValue;
        Value = value;
    }

    public static Bag<TValue> Empty
    {
        get { return new Bag<TValue>(default(TValue), false); }
    }

    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }
    public TValue Value { get; private set; }
}
```

so I can write following code

```
    public static Bag<XElement> GetXElement(this XElement element, string elementName)
    {
        try
        {
            XElement result = element.Element(elementName);
            return result == null
                       ? Bag<XElement>.Empty
                       : new Bag<XElement>(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Bag<XElement>.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Looks like nullable but not only for value type

Another example

```
    public static Bag<string> TryParseString(this XElement element, string attributeName)
    {
        Bag<string> attributeResult = GetString(element, attributeName);
        if (attributeResult.HasValue)
        {
            return new Bag<string>(attributeResult.Value);
        }
        return Bag<string>.Empty;
    }

    private static Bag<string> GetString(XElement element, string attributeName)
    {
        try
        {
            string result = element.GetAttribute(attributeName).Value;
            return new Bag<string>(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Bag<string>.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `try` `catch` will wreak havoc on your performance if you're calling `GetXElement()` and failing many times.

Comment: sometime it's doesn't matter. Take a look on Bag call. Thanks for your observation

Comment: your Bag<T> clas is almost identical to System.Nullable<T> aka "nullable object"

Comment: yes, almost `public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct` the main difference in a constraint. btw the latest version is here https://github.com/Nelibur/Nelibur/blob/master/Source/Nelibur.Sword/DataStructures/Option.cs

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the "magic value" route, yet another way to solve this is to overload the purpose of the Lazy class.  Although Lazy is intended to defer instantiation, nothing really prevents you from using like a Maybe or an Option.   For instance:

```
    public static Lazy<TValue> GetValue<TValue, TKey>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
        TKey key)
    {
        TValue retVal;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out retVal))
        {
            var retValRef = retVal;
            var lazy = new Lazy<TValue>(() => retValRef);
            retVal = lazy.Value;
            return lazy;
        }

        return new Lazy<TValue>(() => default(TValue));
    }
```